# Variance related conditions in pandas hierarchy dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    df
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Val1
    A       C       E       50
    A       C       F       30
    A       D       E       15
    A       D       F       5
    B       C       E       35
    B       C       F       13
    B       D       E       13
    B       D       F       43
```

I have below condition to apply on the above dataframe: Following are the expected outputs:

```
    df2         : For Col1=A, calculate 90% of Val1 and show which contribute to 90% of Val1 from Col2
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Val1
    A       C       E       50
    A       C       F       30
    A       D       E       15
    
        
    df3         : Out of the Col2 values from step 1, calculate 75% of Val1 and show which contribute to 75% of that value from Col3
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Val1
    A       C       E       50
    A       C       F       30
    

    df3         :Out of the Col3 values from step 2, calculate 45% of Val1 and show which contribute to 45% of that value from Col4 
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Val1
    A       C       E       50
```

Is it possible to do this? I am not able to identify the way to implement that logic wrt dataframes.

Comment: Can You share expected output data to illustrate problem please?

Comment: Can you restate show some code and expected output?

Comment: updated the question with the expected outputs